# Как разрешить другому человеку менять мой сайт на тильде?

Tags: site

Есть сайт на тильде, я его могу редактировать.
Фрилансер просит логин и пароль чтоб зайти через меня и редактировать его. Можно ли как-нибудь по другому дать доступ к редактированию другому человеку?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, **в чём именно вы видите проблему**, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Непонятно, в чём проблема дать пароль. Человек должен выполнить определённую работу, для этого ему нужно дать определённые права, инструменты - а вы их давать не хотите. "С деньгами и дурак купит сигареты, а ты попробуй без денег": с паролем любой сделает, верно? Вы хотя бы обозначьте проблему более наглядно, потому что сейчас вопрос непонятен.

Comment: @peter на свой аккаунт в тильде я тратил деньги, с паролем и логином к моему аккаунту он просто может забрать его себе, или ещё чего. Вот я и спрашиваю, это нормально давать логин и пароль от тильды?